# How to calculate GOP size of a file H264

Tags: video, media, h.264, multimedia, svc

I have a h264 file that extract from YUV format using SVC software. Now, I want to caculate size of each GOP in the h264 file. We know that size of GOP is the distance between two nearest I frame. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures). Could you suggest to me how to cacluate the GOP size of a given h264 file. It is better when we implement it by C/C++.Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, just parsing the bitstream to find the each I-frame is a bit tricky; among other things the encode order might be (or not) different from the display-order. One solution is to use http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html from the ffmpeg-suite.

Example:

```
ffprobe -show_frames input.bin | grep key_frame
key_frame=1
key_frame=0
key_frame=0
key_frame=0
key_frame=0
key_frame=0
...
```

from the output you can easily calculate the GOP-length

Another solution is to patch the reference implementation found at http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/

Let me know if you need help with this part :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. But in my case, I used SVC to extract YUV to h264 bit stream. It is very difficult to detect which is key frame. Do you have other solution?

Comment: Firstly, what is SVC? You encode an YCbCr file into a H.264 bistream and you would like to get the GOP-length from that file or any other H.264 for that matter?

Comment: SVC is Scalable Video Coding. That's right. My goal is get GOP length from H264 stream

Comment: Someone is actually using SVC? :-) If you don't like the ffmpeg-solution, have a look att the reference sw that I linked to in my answer. The binary `ldecod.exe` outputs the frametype to stdout. It would also be quite simple to add a counter in the src-code to count the frame-number difference between IDR (I)-frames.

Answer (score 16):

I personally prefer filtering by pict_type:

```
ffprobe -show_frames input.h264 | grep pict_type
```

This will show you the frame structure:

```
pict_type=I
pict_type=P
pict_type=P
pict_type=P
pict_type=P
pict_type=P
...
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/sh

ffprobe -show_frames $1 > output.txt

GOP=0;

while read p; do
  if [ "$p" = "key_frame=0" ]
  then
    GOP=$((GOP+1))
  fi

if [ "$p" = "key_frame=1" ]
then
  echo $GOP
  GOP=0;
fi

done < output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every GOP starts with a keyframe you need to count those.
`pict_type` can be misleading as all types can occur inside GOP.

```
ffprobe -show_frames video_file.h264  | grep -A 3 "type=video" | grep "key_frame=1" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
ffprobe -i video_file.h264 -show_frames -of flat |grep I
```

```
frames.frame.1.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.308.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.805.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.1282.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.1750.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.2221.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.2620.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.3178.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.3693.pict_type="I"
```

Answer (score -1):

use command like:

```
ffprobe -show_entries frame=pict_type  mp4_sample.mp4  -of flat | grep I
```

and you will see the result like:

```
frames.frame.0.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.384.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.764.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.1027.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.1164.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.1544.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.1944.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.2183.pict_type="I"
frames.frame.2324.pict_type="I"
```